# Setting a telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn default value

Tags: telerik-grid

I have a Telerik RadGrid with a GridCheckBoxColumn.  When the user clicks the "Add New" button, I want to default the GridCheckBoxColumn to "true".  How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set DefaultInsertValue="True" for the column